# No more context in templates when passing debug to False

Tags: python, django

When debug is set to True in settings, the site works normally, but when I put debug to False, it becomes very slow and I have no more context request in templates.

Template is called like that :

```
return render_to_response('base.html', {"content": pres},RequestContext(request))
```

And in my settings, context processors defined are :

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'context_processors.languages',
)
```

I tested lot of things, I don't understand the issue.

Comment: do you have a `settings.DEBUG` condition somewhere which is not loading the context?

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with it but what if you try explicitly setting context_instance? Ex. `return render_to_response('base.html', {"content": pres}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: does not change anything

Comment: The issue was just due to the ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py which was empty, filling it with '*' resolve it.